# How to send data to Google Form with multiple pages?

Tags: http, google-forms

My Google Form consist of 13 pages. I need to send data from my mobile app to this form via Http request. So I created i big URL with all my params. But in response I see that only one page was filled, and other date was lost. So how can I send data to google Form which consist from a lot of pages?

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I have solved this porblem. So, for sending data to Google Form, which consist of more than 1 page, it is necessary to add **pageHistory** param into URL or to request body. For example

```
https://docs.google.com/a/forms/d/1pn4CNQ7OwKce4K7ebb_2RZQ6PmFBf-5Qxp8zfdajgSw/formResponse?entry.1748727384=1&entry.1949164265=1&pageHistory=0,1,2&submit=Submit
```

Hope it will be usefull for others